# PowerShell IIS:\ WebAdmin Remote Invocation triggers WSAStartup error, WSANOTINITIALISED

Tags: powershell, wsastartup

I'm using PSRemoting with the WebAdministration module to get info about various sites, and it's working. I am, however, receiving an annoying non-fatal COM exception during invocation of the command, and wondering if anyone else has resolved it. Here's a minimal implementation:

```
cls
$command = {
    param($alias)
    Import-Module 'WebAdministration'
    $binding = Get-WebBinding -HostHeader $alias
    $binding
}

$server = 'server'
$args = @('alias')
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server
Write-Host ("Invoking")
try {
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $command -ArgumentList $args
    Write-Host ("Invoked")
} catch {
    Write-Host ("Caught $_")
} finally {
    Write-Host ("Removing")
    Remove-PSSession -Session $session
    Write-Host ("Removed")
}
```

And here are the results:

```
Invoking

protocol           : http
bindingInformation : 10.x.x.x:80:alias
...
Schema             : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema

An unhandled COM interop exception occurred: Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800
7276D)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException

Invoked
Removing
Removed
```

I observe the result is returned prior to the error being thrown.

Amusing details:
 - Get-Website, Get-Item "IIS:\...", Get-WebBinding all result in the same error
 - Running $command directly on the target machine as written results in no error
 - Get-Item "d:\..." does not result in any error
 - The COM error doesn't

Comment: I've run this code from 3 separate W2k8 servers in PowerGUI and Powershell prompt and against 2 different target servers. In all cases I received the same error.

Comment: Interestingly, NetMon shows the encrypted conversation with /wsman is very similar between a failing WebAdmin session and a "succeeding" Get-Item 'd:\' session. Both conversations end with the remote server sending back encrypted data, then (to the last post, theoretically a disconnect request?) a 500 Internal Server Error. No real information there, since I can't decrypt the conversation, but interesting.

Comment: Since I'm in verbose mode, I'll add this is important because my internal clients will see the error and bother me. To that end, and until I find a real resolution, I've added " -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" to my remote invoke. It handles the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is buried somewhere deep in the bowels of PowerShell's implementation of .NET and winsock. It's below anything I can calibrate, so I've added " -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" to my remote invoke. It doesn't fix anything, but everything works correctly. That's answer enough for now, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around the issue using the following:

```
    $iisIpAddresses = Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {
    if (!(Get-Module WebAdministration)) 
    {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
    }
    $iisBindings = Get-WebBinding
    [String[]]$iisBindings = $iisBindings | Select bindingInformation
    $iisBindings
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```